# Why is there a number in the zsh parameter expansion ${1-$PWD}

Tags: shell, zsh, variable-substitution

I have this script I'm basing my current script off of. I just don't understand why he has `typeset result part dir=${1-$PWD}` in there.

I get the same result if I just write `dir=$PWD`. With typeset is `${1-$PWD}` changing how `dir` is set vs `$PWD`?

Comment: There's a question for every possible variation of this particular form of parameter expansion... [What does this line in bash do? Parameter-||scriptname](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236631), or [Bourne shell: trailing `-` operator in parameter substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191873), or [Using “${a:-b}” for variable assignment in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122845) etc...

Comment: I'll just link the relevant section of the standard here, too. There's a nice table describing the `${var*word}` expansions (for different values of `*`): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`${1-$PWD}` is a shell parameter expansion pattern.

It is used to expand to a default value based on another -- whatever on the right of `-`. Here, in your case:

- If `$1` is unset, then the expansion of `$PWD` would be substituted
- Otherwise i.e. if `$1` is set to any value (including null), its value would be used as the result of expansion

**Example:**

```
% echo "Foo${1-$PWD}"   
Foo/home/bar

% set -- Spam

% echo "Foo${1-$PWD}"
FooSpam
```

Answer (score 8):

That's not brace expansion, that's a standard parameter expansion operator (dates back to the Bourne shell in the 70s).

```
${1-$PWD}
```

Expands to the value of `$1` (the first positional parameter) if it is set (if `$#` is strictly greater than 0) even to the empty string, or to the content of the `$PWD` variable otherwise.

Run:

```
info zsh 'Parameter Expansion'
```

for details.

`typeset` is not Bourne nor POSIX, but it's not `zsh`-specific either. It comes from the Korn shell (from the early 80s) and is used to limit the scope of a variable to the current function. It's also found in `bash` and `yash`.

Run:

```
info zsh typeset
```

for details.

Answer (score 4):

It tests `$1` for a value, using that before `$PWD`.